# The program stuck when request a asynchronous ftp request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asynchronous

I encountered a problem when I am doing ftp request asynchronously, I try to describe the exact problem clearly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //I want to do a ftpListRequst in the background here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        NewFTPListService *nfl = [[NewFTPListService alloc] initWithFtpPath:@"ftp://root:@10.0.0.3/"];

        [nfl listDirectoryContents];

        [nfl release];

    }); 

    //other main thread code
}

- (NSArray *) listDirectoryContents
{   
    [_listDir start];

    //What I want to do here is to wait until the ftp request finish
    while (!self.isFinish) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Request Finish!");

    return self.result;
}

-(void) start {
    ......
    self.streamInfo->readStream.delegate = self;
    [self.streamInfo->readStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.streamInfo->readStream open];

    //If request is blocked (may be the server is not avaliable), after a specific time, this block will be called
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, kWRDefaultTimeout * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{       
        [self.delegate requestFailed:self];
        [self destroy];
    });

}
```

When successfully doing request, this method will be called:

```
-(void) requestCompleted:(WRRequest *) request{

    self.isSucess = YES;
    self.isFinish = YES;
}
```

This method will be called in the "dispatch_after" block

```
-(void) requestFailed:(WRRequest *) request{
    self.isSucess = NO;
    self.isFinish = YES; 
}
```

When reqeust successfully, I see the print "Request Finish!". When request is blocked and the  "dispatch_after" block is called, then "requestFailed" method is called, but I do not see the print "Request Finish!". It seems that the program is somehow stuck at the while loop (The loop is not running , the code after do not run either).

What is more, if I run the program synchronously:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NewFTPListService *nfl = [[NewFTPListService alloc] initWithFtpPath:@"ftp://root:@10.0.0.3/"];

        [nfl listDirectoryContents];

        [nfl release];
    }
```

Even if the request is failed, I can successfully see the print "Request Finish!". I want to know why this happened and how to fix this problem so that I could successfully run the program when the request is failed. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what [self destroy] is doing?

Comment: @DarthMike self.streamInfo->bytesConsumedThisIteration = 0;
    self.streamInfo->bytesConsumedInTotal = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just call this method by performSelector

```
[nfl listDirectoryContents];
```

or call this method in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: YES, I can solve the problem with performSelector. But the main thread will be blocked.